# How to make MongoDB find nested json return as an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5461e16ee7caf96f8f3584a2"),
    "num_marcacao" : "100",
    "sexo" : "Fêmea",
    "idade" : "20",
    "bigdata" : {
        "abortos" : [ 
            {
                "data_aborto" : "2014-11-11",
                "causa_aborto" : "Aborto causa 1"
            }, 
            {
                "data_aborto" : "2014-09-01",
                "causa_aborto" : "Aborto causa 2"
            }
        ],
        "crias" : [ 
            ObjectId("5461e16ee7caf96f8f3584a2")
         ]
     }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5461e1cae7caf96f8f3584a4"),
    "num_marcacao" : "200",
    "sexo" : "Fêmea",
    "bigdata" : {
       "crias" : [ 
           ObjectId("5461e1f3e7caf96f8f3584a5"), 
           ObjectId("5461e760e7caf96f8f3584a6")
       ]
    }
}
```

Using the following distinct function I get one result

```
db.animal.distinct('_id', {'bigdata.crias':{$exists:true}}
```

Result:

```
{
    "0" : ObjectId("5461e16ee7caf96f8f3584a2"),
    "1" : ObjectId("5461e1cae7caf96f8f3584a4")
}
```

Now I want to get the array that is in `bigdata.crias` like the result of the distinct query.
I'm trying to do like this:

```
db.animal.find(
    {
        $and: [
            {'num_marcacao': '200'},
            {'bigdata.crias':{$exists: true}}
        ]
    },
    {
        'bigdata.crias': true,
        '_id': false
    }
)
```

But the result is not like the one I need. This is what it's returning:

```
{
    "bigdata" : {
        "crias" : [ 
            ObjectId("5461e1f3e7caf96f8f3584a5"), 
            ObjectId("5461e760e7caf96f8f3584a6")
        ]
    }
}
```

And I need

```
{
    "0" : ObjectId("5461e1f3e7caf96f8f3584a5"),
    "1" : ObjectId("5461e760e7caf96f8f3584a6")
}
```

Comment: You should probably add a "php" tag since your notation is a "php" representation of an array ( and php has a very different idea of arrays to the rest of the world ). But you are getting exactly what you are asking for. What is the problem with just inspecting the relevant item in the object? Oh, I'll add the tag for you.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for the reply and for tagging it. I forgot to mention that I'm using Node.js to execute these querys. I want to use the result of one query at an `$in` aggregate function. The result as an array with [1]: "Text" I can use at a "subquery", but the result with nested json can't be used for that propose, at least the way I'm tying...

Comment: Funny because usually people who represent and array like `{ "0": {}, "1": {} }` have a php background. You mention using aggregate but you don't show it. Aggregate will never return a raw array as the result without being under a key. The [`.distinct()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) method however "does" support a "query" argument. There is a link there. So do you really need an answer to explain it or should that be enough? Just asking.

Comment: The function that I'm using is this one `db.animal.find({'_id':{$in:db.animal.distinct('_id', {'bigdata.crias':{$exists:true}})}})`. See that I'm using a subquery (distinct) to get what I want. I don't know if this is the best practice or if I should get the result of the distinct in one request then make another request passing the array as parameter. About the `.distinct()`, I can pass a query like aggregate as parameter to the `.distinct()`? Because as far as I know I can pass just simple `.find()` query as parameter, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyhow. MongoDB does not generally do this from either the `.find()` or `.aggregate()` methods or anything general around them. Only the [`.distinct()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) method invokes a special form where the result given is "truly" just an array of the specified "key" to be distinct on.

You can always "inspect" the object returned and just use the array element in the structure. You can also specify a "query" argument to the [`.distinct()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) command method in the first place:

```
db.collection.distinct(
    "bigdata.crias",
    { 
        "bigdata.crias": { "$exists": true },
        "num_marcacao": "200"
    }
);
```

Where you also see your [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) argument is redundant. All MongoDB query arguments are an "and" implementation by default. You don't need this unless you are specifying "more than one" condition on the same "field name". That would result in an invalid object by breaking the basic "hash/map" "unique key" rule, and which is why and "array" is used for this form to keep it valid.

Comment: I guess I can now work based on your explanation. Thanks for the atention.